# Shrink-wrap and center a container for inline-block elements

Tags: containers, center, css

I have a bunch of inline-block elements over several lines which I'd like to center horizontally. The inline-block elements all have the same fixed size, but I'd like the centering to be able to handle page resizing and adding or removing elements.

I've stripped down the html/css and removed the attempt at centering for clarity. It's at http://jsfiddle.net/fe25H/1/

If you resize the results window so that the third inline-block element drops down, the container fills the width and we get this:

```
-----------------BODY------------------
|                                     |
||-------------CONTAINER-------------||
||-INLINEBLOCK---INLINEBLOCK--       ||
|||____________||____________|       ||
||-INLINEBLOCK--                     ||
|||____________|                     ||
||___________________________________||
|_____________________________________|
```

rather than this:

```
-----------------BODY------------------
|                                     |
|   |----------CONTAINER---------|    |
|   |-INLINEBLOCK---INLINEBLOCK--|    |
|   ||____________||____________||    |
|   |-INLINEBLOCK--              |    |
|   ||____________|              |    |
|   |____________________________|    |
|_____________________________________|
```

edit based on ptriek's answer regarding a JavaScript solution:

Ptriek's code was a useful starting point; it works for the specific case, but not the general one. I've mostly rewritten it to be more flexible (see http://jsfiddle.net/fe25H/5/).

Comment: interesting question, pretty curious if there's a non-javascript solution for this...

Comment: As soon as an element wraps to the next line, the container will assume a width of 100%. This isn't possible without Javascript.

Comment: What if you used a pseudo-element to fill the extra space? I'm currently trying that, but with little luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking a bit about it, I agree with Wex' comment above.

So I fiddled a JavaScript solution (jQuery) - I'm not an expert on this, so the code might be improved - but I guess it does exactly what you need:

```js
var resizeContainer = function () {
    var w_window = $(window).width();
    var w_block = $('.inlineblock').width();
    if (w_window < w_block * 3 && w_window >= w_block * 2) {
        $('.container').width(w_block * 2);
    } else if (w_window < w_block * 2) {
        $('.container').width(w_block);
    }  else {
        $('.container').width(w_block * 3);
    } 
};


$(document).ready(resizeContainer);
$(window).resize(resizeContainer);
```

```css
body {
    text-align:center;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align:left;
}
.inlineblock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/fe25H/4/

Comment: Thanks, see the edit to the original question where I've improved the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stated is, as far as my CSS knowledge will take me, not perfectly solvable with purely CSS.

**Mike M. Lin**'s answer is a very ingenious method, I love the creativity, but there are some errors with it that I can expand on.

NOTE: If anyone finds out the general solution, please let us know, since no-body has done it. Etsy, Amazon, Redbubble, can't see this being achieved anywhere...

---

1)

You do not need "2 minus the length of the array of div items", this could get computationally expensive for large n of items. Rather, as an approximate rule, you need enough placeholder "blocks" to create a new line in the container. In fact, the number of placeholders is (in pseudocode):

```
let n = number of block items to display
let n_max = number of block items that fit into one row
let n_ph = number of "placeholder" block items

/*if number of items exceeds max number for a row (starts a new line), then 
 you'll need to start another line with n_max - 1 placeholders*/
if n >= n_max then
    n_ph = n_max - 1
end if

//you don't need any placeholders if number of items fills all rows completely
if n % n_max == 0 then
    n_ph = 0
end if
```

Notice that I have omitted the case when *n < n_max*. That is difficult, and you will have to play around with your *n_ph* values for when *n < n_max*.
If you need *n_ph* to work for different window sizes, I would consider adding a window width observer and adding or taking away a placeholder for your "responsive" width bands. It is a pain, but you will likely either not have *n < n_max* ever, or, your *n_max* is small and it's not a pain to "manually taylor" *n_ph* for the responsive bands.

2)

You don't need the container to be `inline-block`. It works with or without it I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can add invisible placeholders to the end of your inline blocks. That will left-align the last row.

http://jsfiddle.net/aakt65x4/

However, if you don't fill up the first row, the entire thing will appear left-aligned.

**HTML:**

```
<!--
  Centers a group of boxes that wrap to the width of its container.
  Also left-aligns them inside the container.
  Issue: Does not center group if there aren't enough boxes to fill
  the first row.
  -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>

    <!--
      How many placeholders do you need?
      At least the number of blocks minus two.
      -->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center;     /* center a max-width container */
    font-size: 0;           /* remove spaces between blocks */
}
.container {                /* you don't need this */
    background-color: #eee; /* so you can see what's happening */
    max-width: 960px;       /* to demonstrate the centering of a max-width container */
    display: inline-block;  /* center the max-width container */
    text-align: center;     /* center the group of blocks */
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;  /* left-align within the group */
    background-color: red;  /* so you can see what's happening */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.placeholder {
    display: inline-block;  /* add to the line of blocks */
    width: 120px;           /* width + margin of a block */
}
```