# CSS Re-Centering elements on wrap

Tags: css, responsive-design

I thought this would be simple but it's proving to be a bit of a headache. I'm trying to get a grid of images to re-center when the user resizes the browser and causes one (or more) of them to wrap onto the next line.

I've tried giving the grid-wrapper  display:inline-block; and it's parent a value of text-align: center; but this doesn't re-center the elements when they wrap to a new line. Help appreciated.

For a visual of what I'm trying to achieve view [image: picture here]
<sub>(source: [ianclarke.ca](http://ianclarke.ca/div-reflow.png))</sub>
.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <!-- Worpress loop to load many thumnails -->
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-wrapper
{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}

.child-wrapper
{
display:inline-block;
}

.project-thumbnail{
float:left;
border:2px solid black;
min-width: 269px;
max-width: 269px;
}
```

Comment: Why not `width: 269px`?

Comment: You will need to put `.child-wrapper` within the each loop to have it copied to each child. or give `display: inline-block;` to `.project-thumbnail` and ditch out `.child-wrapper`

Comment: Your screenshot is not correct based on the code you have, the last item should be in the center or almost center. i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/6qp5g8yd/

Comment: @Adam - yes doh!

@ Nico O - I think I tried that before but will try again. 

@ sdcr - the visual represents the ideal scenario, where wrapped thumbnails would still be left aligned. Perhaps I need to add another wrapper?

Comment: @ian-clarke - this is one of the best question description I have see in recent times. It has a Problem Statement + Description + Visuals + Code. Perfect composition of the problem and desired result. :) Cheers :)

Comment: I think you just need to update the current resize view image, which isn't correct. But I understood what you want to have. Is jQuery being considered?

Comment: After implementing @Nico's idea… we are getting there. All elements are now centering correctly – so if a single thumbnail is on the second row, it's positioned in the middle. My dream is to have it aligned to the left while the whole grid of images is centered.

Comment: Using JavaScript (most likely by sizing `.child-wrapper` on resize), and your current CSS that you have posted with your question, is the only solution to get that *orphaned* element positioned to the left. It can't be done with the current CSS spec any other way.

Comment: @Adam that's what it looks like. TW posted a JS option that I'm trying out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best solution I can think of with CSS only, the magic part is the @media queries. Obviously you'll have to do the math to fit your case.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqwwp0zc/)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.parent-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
.child-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.child-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .parent-wrapper { width: 400px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    .parent-wrapper { width: 300px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 299px) {
    .parent-wrapper { width: 200px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 199px) {
    .parent-wrapper { width: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-wrapper">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it out now. I'll probably end up with a few breakpoints but it's a lot cleaner than invisible placeholders.

Comment: I went with this solution as I could automate it pretty quickly in SASS and it involved no extra elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very similar question with two functional answers. One uses JS and the other uses placeholder elements. Neither are very pretty, but both appear to work around the inline-block whitespace wrap problem here.

[Shrink-wrap and center a container for inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684793/shrink-wrap-and-center-a-container-for-inline-block-elements)

Comment: These are sounding like the only true way to achieve this :( 
I will try the JS way and let you know if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.child-wrapper{margin:0 auto;}
```

So it stays centered? It usually works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but no luck. The child-wrapper does "shrink to fit" the thumbnails, but once a thumbnail wraps to the next line the child div takes on the width of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `float:left` to class `.project-thumbnail` for the browser breakpoints specific to different browser / screen/device sizes.

```
.project-thumbnail{
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black;
    min-width: 269px;
    max-width: 269px;
}
```

Add `margin: 0, auto;` to following class.

```
.child-wrapper
{
    margin: 0, auto;
}
```

Going through the `PHP` code I understood that the `DIV` with the class name `.project-thumbnail` gets repeated through `WHILE` loop iterations.

Comment: My apologies, project-thumbnail does have a float:left attribute, I was editing out unnecessary styles to keep the question clear and deleted that one by accident. I have a wireframe visual of the page at the top to give you a sense of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. Nice to see your concern of cleaning the code before you post it here. I appreciate it. :) . Have also included the `margin:0 auto;` to `.child-wrapper` class???

Comment: I tried that with no luck, right now what's (almost) working is the the old parent - text:aligned center and child - display:inline-block trick. However my thumbnails that wrap to a new line are center aligned. I'd like them to be left aligned.