# I want to center left floated list items

Tags: css

I have something like this:

http://codepen.io/apijay/pen/RPxRNN

```
<ul>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
</ul>

li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Option 1  |  Option 2  |  Option 3  |  Option 4  |  Option 5 | Option 6 |

------------------------Option 7  |  Option 8---------------------------------

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

But, I want to have something like this so that when screen size changes the margin on left and right size is equal

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

----Option 1  |  Option 2  |  Option 3  |  Option 4  |  Option 5 Option 6----

----Option 7  |  Option 8

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: Same question as this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737863/css-re-centering-elements-on-wrap

Answer (score 0):

To center the `ul`, use `margin: auto;` instead of `text-align: center;`.  (The latter centers the content of the `ul`.)

You'll then need to be careful about `li` children wrapping, which you can prevent like this:

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpoMPr)