# Remove excess width on parent when child elements wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with `display: inline-block;` with a background color.

Inside this div, I add more rectangle divs side by side with `float:left`.

When there is not enough space for all the divs on one line, the next one is added under the others, leaving an empty space on the right side of the page. The empty space left over has the color of the background of my container but I want it to be white.

[image]

The image on the left is what it currently looks like. The image on the right is what it should look like; the parents background should shrink wrap around its children:

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcmLjowv/1/) of the below:

```css
.bigDiv {
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigDiv">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want four in a row?

Comment: so you want to stretch the last div in the line to fill the space till the end of the line? and what did you try?

Comment: Just use percentages and put them together?

Comment: Can you post some CSS and HTML? Are these things variable or fixed width?

Comment: @smnbbrv No, I want the width of the grey part to stop at the 3rd div, not to fill the empty width on the right

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS. The "extra" space is just that...space, not an element and so it can't be styled or selected. This behaviour is standard for all box models as far as I know,

Comment: @Paulie_D Can't I force my grey div to fit the width of its content ?

Comment: @IggY Nope...the box-model / block formatting just doesn't work that way. You're trying the ultimate "shrink-wrap" and AFAIK...it's not possible. Love to find out I'm wrong though.

Comment: There is an existing duplicate question somewhere on SO which was given a javascript solution. Only way this is possible. I remember it from a year or so ago.

Comment: @IggY - I made a few edits to the question, there is nothing wrong with it and I'm trying to make it clearer :)

Comment: @misterManSam Possibly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684793/shrink-wrap-and-center-a-container-for-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating "pseudo-backgrounds"

I have just come up with a somewhat... creative solution:

- The parent is not given a background, only padding and `overflow: hidden`
- Each child div is given a `::before` pseudo element that will create a "pseudo-background" (`z-index: -1` moves it behind the divs background)
- The pseudo-background is positioned with `top`, `left` and `right` with negative values that drag them into the divs padding.
- The `height: 1000%` can be any absurd number, as long as it is tall enough to cover every row of divs. The excess is cleanly cut off with `overflow: hidden` on the parent div

This is what each div looks like, the black border is the edge of the parent which is where the yellow "pseudo-background" is cut off:

[image: Screenshot 1]

it becomes this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Note:** This is a purely visual thought experiment, which may be useful in some cases. The div is still taking up the same width, it just has no background color.

#### Example

Resize it, see how the "pseudo-background" works at all widths.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  width: 70%;
}
.wrapper > div {
  height: 40px;
  background: #F00;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper > div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 1000%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Obviously this is a visual solution only as the actual container will still have the *extra* width. Interesting though.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I don't want to use the extra width so it's perfect for me ! Thank's.
If someone could provide me a link explaining why it is so complicated to do that I'd love it !

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case of `<table>` or better, **FlexBox**:

**Preview:**

[image]

**Snippet:**

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  border: 1px solid #99f;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Same CSS, infinite entries.

Comment: Not in this case I don't think...that's not what he's after,...at least as far as he knows.

Comment: @Paulie_D Check out my updated snippet. Just updated.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I don't want all the divs to fit in one line, I'm fine with the way they are positioned. What I want is the enclosing div with background color to not fill all the width of the page but stop at the 3rd div of the first line, to not have a grey margin on the right as shown on the screenshot

Comment: But you're not addressing his color issue. He's happy with the wrapping...is the color underneath he wants to affect. I agree flexbox might be more appropriate for what he *needs* but that's not what he's asking for,

Comment: @Paulie_D Now I understood. Please have a look at the updated fiddle. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Something like this? Or am I totally missing the mark? https://jsfiddle.net/swx2cux7/1/

Comment: Nope...unfortunately, you're still stretching elements not shrinkwrapping the container. As I said in the comments. this isn't possible AFAIK. Perfect shrinkwrapping of floats & inline blocks isn't possible and flexbox doesn't change that....at least AFAIK

Comment: @IggY Try giving a `float: left` to the parent `<div>`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I made a fiddle and added a screenshot to explain better what I did and what I want

Comment: There is an existing duplicate question somewhere on SO which was given a javascript solution. Only way this is possible. I remember it from a year or so ago.

Comment: Yeah...I'm sure this is s dupe too. I'd love to get to grips with why the *extra* space is there. It's something to do with `line-box` or something like that.